# java.net.UnknownHostException on opening connection to https site

Tags: java, authentication, javafx, webview, proxy

its been a month since i begun java programming. in meantime, im working on a java fx webview running on authenticated proxy unit. I was able to connect on http site running this code :

```
Properties systemSettings = System.getProperties();
    String User = "myusername";
    String Password = "mypassword";
    systemSettings.put("proxySet", "true");
    systemSettings.put("https.proxyHost", "192.1.1.20");
    systemSettings.put("https.proxyPort", "8888");
    systemSettings.put("http.proxyHost", "192.1.1.20");
    systemSettings.put("http.proxyPort", "8888");
    Authenticator.setDefault(new ProxyAuthenticator(User ,Password));

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://www.google.com/").openConnection();
    String encodedUserPwd = Base64Converter.encode("myuser:mypassword".getBytes());

    conn.setRequestProperty("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic " + encodedUserPwd);

    conn.connect();


    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    }

    WebView webView = new WebView();
    WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
    engine.load("http://www.google.com/");

    VBox root = new VBox();
    root.getChildren().addAll(webView);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1200, 700);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    in.close();
```

but if i changed the url to https it throws java.net.UnknownHostException. need help.

Comment: btw, im trying to access on google maps site.

Comment: Did you try connecting through a proxy via your browser or curl?

Comment: via javafx webview. sorry but im not particular with curl.

Comment: Try connecting with a browser (via the proxy) to check if it's a Java issue or a proxy issue

Comment: im good connecting via proxy on browser using my own credentials.

Comment: you have two places where you call somethign: `HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://www.google.com/").openConnection();`and `engine.load("http://www.google.com/");`. Which one throws the error?

Comment: this one  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://www.google.com/").openConnection();
btw, Webview wont open google if connection wasnt established first.

Comment: anyone wants to help?